# Set paging distance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, paging

Is there a way to set a custom paging distance for an UIIScrollView? So you can have a scrollview with a width of 330 and it pages every 110? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can achieve this via UITableView, setting cell height to 110, i think

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question and provided wrong answer. Consider my answer irrelevant and deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This property is not customizable. By default scroll view takes its frame width as the page width.